# For loop through temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

i have a temporary table in a `function(postgresql)`

```
create temporary table temp_table (
id serial
,breakup_id integer
,enquiry_id integer
,estimate_id integer
,customer_name CHARACTER VARYING
,month integer
,year integer
,amount numeric
) on commit drop;
```

I need to `for loop` this temporary table to update `amount` column using `breakup_id` . How to do that in `postgresql function`?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Comment: You already have a function ?,  Remove extraneous tag

Comment: Why a loop? A simple `update set amount = 42 where breakup_id in (1,2,3)` will do.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe thq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have some complicated logic for value of amount, use

```
do 
$$ 
declare _r record; 
begin 
  for _r in (select * from temp_table) loop 
    update temp_table set amount='complicated calculated values' where id = _r.id; 
  end loop; 
end; 
$$
;
```

Otherwise use `UPDATE temp_table set amount = /*simple value*/ where id=..`

And lastly - remember that temporary table is not meant to keep data - Eg you wont be able to read data from it with other backend...